# NoUiSlider not working in react project

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, nouislider

I am trying to use nouislider in my react application but it is not working. I can see the slider but I the sliderbutton is not moving or getting slided. I have initialized it as suggested in docs. THis is my code

```
 componentDidMount(){


        var noUi_slider = document.getElementById('noUiSlider');
        noUiSlider.create(noUi_slider, {
            start: 40,
            connect: true,
            range: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            }
        });
```

And this how it looks

[image]

I cannot drag the slider. It doesn't move but when inspected, the values of slider are changing. That means the movement is not visible. How should I solve this?